# Emacs rx semantics

Tags: emacs, regex

I have the constructed the following regular expresion using rx.el module

```
   (rx (and bol (0+ (not (any "#" "[]*" "\n")))  " " (or "#" "[]*") " "))
```

I want to change the string []* for the string ~=[,,_,,]:3 but when I write the following

```
(rx (and bol
             (0+ (not (any "#" "~=[,,_,,]:3" "\n")))
             " "
             (or "#" "~=[,,_,,]:3")
             " "))
```

rxt-explain shows that that it is getting compiled to the wrong regexp

```
(sequence line-start
          (zero-or-more
           (not
            (any "~" "[" ":" "," "\n" "]" "#" "3" "=" "_")))
          " "
          (or
           (any "#")
           "~=[,,_,,]:3")
          " ")
```

Any ideas on how to fix the regexp expresion so that it treats the "~[,,_,,]:3" as a group?

Comment: Could you post a example of a string you expect to match, or rather an example of a string that you would like to avoid? Because your square brackets notation seems weird to me. It might not be what you expect.

Comment: It is basically to detect the eshell prompt. The []* is a short emoticon of nyan-cat's while the latter is longer one. What I would like to match 0 or more characters that don't have this two characters "\n" and "#" and nor the string "~[,,_,,]:3" which in the original regexp prompt was "$"

Comment: Frigging rx.el.   It is creating a problem by its very existence. Regular Expressions are well defined, well known, in broad use.  rx.el comes along and invents a NEW! BETTER!  NOVEL!!!  syntax that we all need to learn. Wrong idea. What problem are we solving here?